# How to make a function like Set, but with a Block construct for the pattern names

Tags: programming, assignment, function-construction

How can we define a function that works like  `f[x_]=ComputeSomething[x]`  and treats `x`  as a variable that does not have a value?  We could call this function `LocalSet` and the computation should be done when the assignment is made as in the following example.

```
var=3;
LocalSet[f[var_],Normal[Series[Exp[var],{var,0,3}]]];
DownValues[f]

(*
---> {HoldPattern[f[var_]]:>1+var+var^2/2+var^3/6}
*)

var
(*
---> 3
*)
```

Notice I don't want to be limited to a pattern variable (`x_`).  The function called `LocalSet` should figure out what symbols are used for patterns and evalute the right side with those variables in a `Block` construct.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
SetAttributes[localSet, HoldAll]

localSet[lhs_, rhs_] := 
  Union @@ Cases[
    Unevaluated[lhs], 
    Verbatim[Pattern][p_, _] :> HoldComplete[p],
    Infinity,
    Heads -> True
  ] /. _[x___] :> Block[{x}, lhs = rhs;]
```

Test:

```
var=3;
localSet[f[var_],Normal[Series[Exp[var],{var,0,3}]]]
DownValues[f]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[f[var_]] :> 1 + var + var^2/2 + var^3/6}
> ```

Comment: I came up with almost exactly the same code. Hope you don't mind my edit to make it work in more general cases and avoid returning a value.

Comment: It not only about *returning* a value.  It's about evaluating the expression, which might have side effects or unintended consequences. Consider `f[x_?NumericQ] := (Print["numeric"]; x); n = 5; localSet[g[n_], f[n]]`, which has different behaviour when the semicolon is omitted.  I think it's important here that the expression not be evaluated with `n` having a value---there's no telling what that might lead to.

Comment: +1. I would write the same code, except including `Heads->True` option in `Cases`, if you want to cover `SubValues`. Right now an attempt to assign to say `f[var_][1]` will produce an error. If you want to be totally safe, I'd also use `HoldComplete` in place of `Hold`.

Comment: @Leonid, thank you, I will add `Heads -> True`.  Regarding `HoldComplete` I hesitate to use it unless I know it is needed because there are times it is not wanted.  If you have a different opinion you know I would like to hear it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  Well, imagine someone is crazy or careless enough to execute this at some point: `ClearAll[var];var /: _[var] := var; var = 3;` The current version of `localSet` won't work then. This is of course a rather contrived example, but if we want to make things robust, any example should work. For this case, I don't see how `HoldComplete` can bring any unwanted effects, so I'd use it.

Comment: @Leonid to confirm: {`HoldAll` -> `HoldAllComplete`, `Hold` -> `HoldComplete`} correct?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Actually, `HoldAll` may be enough, so just `Hold`-> `HoldComplete` I think.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The possible troublesome symbols will be deeper than level one during the call to `localSet[f[...],rhs]`, because they will be inside `f`. So, as long as `localSet` is `HoldAll`, you don't have to care about them, exactly due to the depth-1 limitation for `UpValues` search. But when you destructure, you have `Hold[sym]`, and here `HoldComplete` is essential.

Comment: Well, to make it a little bit moore robust it would be better to use a preorder ReplaceAll based Cases that stops inside Verbatims. Something along the lines of `Module[{tag},Reap[Unevaluated[lhs]/.{i_Verbatim:>i, Verbatim[Pattern][p_, _]/;Sow[HoldComplete[p], tag]:>Null}, tag][[1, -1]]]`

Comment: @Rojo Why am I only reading this now? (The notice system is unreliable, that's why.)  Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll have to think that one through, then add it to the answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard it is very unreliable, I miss pings a lot.