# How to plot Fit functions?

Tags: plotting, fitting

If I do something like this

`f[x_]:=x^2`

`Plot[f[x],{x,1,10}]`

Mathematica plots the function $f(x)=x^2$, as expected.  However, if I do something like this instead

`data=Table[x^2,{x,1,10}]`

`f[x_]:=Fit[data,{1,x},x]`

`Plot[f[x],{x,1,10}]`

Mathematica throws me some weird errors such as `-4.9998 is not a valid variable.`  What is going on here?

Comment: As an aside, how is one supposed to go about typesetting multi-line code on this website?  Is there a better way to do it than exiting the code environment, adding spaces, and entering the code environment again?

Comment: @JonathanGleason Are you using `f[x_]:=...` ? It seems you are missing the `=` sign.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Yeah, sorry about that.  That was a typo on here.  In Mathematica, I was using `f[x_]:=...`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of your function `f[x_]` is the problem. Here is the corrected version:

```
data = Table[x^2, {x, 1, 10}]

(* ==> {1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100} *)

f[x_] = Fit[data, {1, x}, x]

(* ==> -22. + 11. x *)

Plot[f[x], {x, 1, 10}]
```

[image: fit]

The mistake was to define the function with `SetDelayed`. In that case, the symbol `x` on the right-hand side of the definition will be given the value with which the function is called, whereas `Fit` expects `x` to be a symbol and *not* a numeric value.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative, you can use `FindFit[]` instead of `Fit[]` for defining your regression function:

```
data = Table[x^2, {x, 1, 10}];
f = Function[x, a + b x] /. FindFit[data, a + b x, {a, b}, x];

Plot[f[x], {x, 1, 10}] ~Show~ ListPlot[data]
```

[image: regression function and points]

This hinges on the fact that `FindFit[]` returns the parameters (as replacement rules) as opposed to the regression function itself, making substitution into the regression model easy.

---

Mr. Wizard reminds me that variable localization might be necessary, especially if this is being done in the midst of a long session, where the variables may have had previous un-`Clear[]`ed assignments. One way to go about it is to use so-called ["formal symbols"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html#173509264) which are guaranteed to never have taken previous values, since you can's assign to them.

Here's how to go about it in this case:

```
f = Function[\[FormalX], \[FormalA] + \[FormalB] \[FormalX]] /.
   FindFit[data, \[FormalA] + \[FormalB] \[FormalX], {\[FormalA], \[FormalB]}, \[FormalX]]
```

(It looks somewhat complicated here, since the SE interface does not have the proper font faces for the characters that denote formal symbols. It looks better when pasted into *Mathematica*.)

Answer (score 3):

An example:

```
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}}

f[x_] = Fit[data, {1, x}, x]

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

Please note that I used `=` instead of `:=`. The right hand side needs to evaluate before being assigned to `f`.

Comment: IMHO you should localize `x` in `Fit`.

Comment: Yeah. Probably.

Answer (score 3):

Also

```
data = Table[x^2, {x, 1, 10}];
f1 = Fit[data, {1, x}, x];
f2 = Fit[data, {1, x^2}, x];
Show[Plot[{f1, f2}, {x, 1, 10}], ListPlot@data]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Note that the following gives you the same result

```
data = Table[x^2, {x, 1, 10}];
f1 = Fit[data, {1, #}, x] & /@ {x, x x}
Show[Plot[f1, {x, 1, 10}], ListPlot@data]
```

Answer (score 3):

At present none of the answers given localize variables during the definition of `f` to protect against global assignments.  For actual use I strongly suggest you do:

```
x = 0; (*example left-over assignment*)

data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}}

Block[{x},
  f[x_] = Fit[data, {1, x}, x]
]

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

Or:

```
f[\[FormalX]_] = Fit[data, {1, \[FormalX]}, \[FormalX]]

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

---

I also wrote [a function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1997/121) `localSet` to answer a prior question which you could use:

```
x = 0; (*example left-over assignment*)

data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}}

localSet[ f[x_], Fit[data, {1, x}, x] ]

DownValues[f]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> 0.186441 + 0.694915 x}
> ```