# Proper way to handle free variables in manipulate/plot?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

It took me a while today to figure out that `Manipulate` (used with `Plot`) requires that the variable I'm manipulating be an actual parameter of the thing that I'm manipulating.

That is, if I have something like:

```
foo = Exp[2 x+y]
Manipulate[Plot[foo, {x, 0, 10}], {y, 0, 10}]
```

It will not work as desired, but if I have:

```
ffoo[x_, y_] := Exp[2 x+y]
Manipulate[Plot[ffoo[x, y], {x, 0, 10}], {y, 0, 10}]
```

It will.

I can't help but wonder; what is the general correct approach here? To me it feels slightly "wrong" that I should need to declare all the free variables for my statements as arguments. But maybe this is just something I should get over. In my case, it means I need to change, say, an arbitrary amount of places where I might call these to get various things (like eigenvectors with free parameters) and do a bunch of work converting them into function calls? Just because I want to use them in plots?

My actual approach was to write little "plot functions" for the particular bits I wanted to plot, and I then I did a little probably-inappropriate trick of just sneaking them into functions:

```
foofunc[a_, b_, c_] := Evalulate[foo]
```

(Knowing that `foo` contains free variables named as "a", "b", etc...).

It seems, though, that there must be a better way of just asking Manipulate to consider implicit parameters (or whatever their formal name is; I tried a bit of searching and wasn't able to find anything about this; though I imagine it's fairly common).

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I wonder why my comment with [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236458/plot-using-with-versus-plot-using-block-mathematica/) was deleted, I find it very relevant here and not linked to by other answers. Anyway, making another one.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Pardon the reply to a very old comment but according to the post history no comments under this question have ever been deleted.  I think there must have been a software glitch.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Well, this is now water under the bridge, anyway. But thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

In my opinion once you start passing objects as functions like this it makes sense to use the named argument form: `ffoo[x_, y_] := Exp[2 x + y]`  Otherwise you risk conflicts with global assignments to `x` and `y`.

Nevertheless there are ways to do what you want more directly I believe, e.g.

```
foo = Exp[2 x + y];

With[{foo = foo},
  Manipulate[Plot[foo, {x, 0, 10}], {y, 0, 10}]
]
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. (I understand the risk about global assignments; arguably that's actually the feature I want - the variables are sensibly named). My problem, really, was getting results back from other functions with these free variables in them (i.e. eigenvectors/values). And also, it seems slightly "semantically" confusing, because my function really only has one actual parameter, but the system itself has these free parameters. I still feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: @NoonSilk I wonder if *I'm* missing something in your application.  Would you consider adding another example to your question, perhaps with the eigenvectors usage that you mention?  At a stretch, perhaps [this method](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8003/121) may be tangentially of interest to you.

Comment: I'm new to Mathematica, so I'm likely wrong. I'm suggesting that, at some point I have a matrix, which has free variables in it (say `x` and `y`). So if I solve for Eigenvalues, I clearly get these free params in the result. So at some point I'll need to write something exactly like `f[H_, x_] := ... Evaluate @ Eigensystem[H]` ... to get the result appropriately back from Eigensystem for use further down the line? Then, I will need to "functionalise" all future things, say a density matrix which is formally a fn only of `t`, to be fn's of the somewhat arbitrary free variables from earlier?

Comment: It seems weird to do so, to me, because I might at some point say "Okay, this variable is no longer free, it is now 10". I'd need to change a random number of function params to fully reflect this, or just now pass a constant around. I guess I'm differentiating "system" variables (by allowing them to be global) from function variables. And this `Manipulate` question has forced me to reconsider how I do that, because it doesn't play nicely with it, with my minimal knowledge. I actually think converting them to functions is probably correct, but only far latter; essentially as I'm doing.

Comment: But the `Evalulate` in there to play the trick of using the same variable name as the function parameter seems like it will get me into trouble at some point.

Comment: @NoonSilk I don't have time to fully address the question of program structuring, and I would like to get some more details from you in Chat before I do anyway (not now).  Know that `f[x_] := Evaluate @ g[x]` is equivalent to `f[x_] = g[x]` -- usually when using this form one should consider protecting against global values as [described here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8554/121) but in your application that may not be a problem.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative method to get the effect you want is to use a replacement rule:

```
Manipulate[Plot[foo /. {y -> b}, {x, 0, 10}], {b, 0, 10}]
```

The issue is that if you write:

```
Manipulate[Plot[foo, {x, 0, 10}], {y, 0, 10}]
```

then you have the `y` that is an expression within the expression `foo`, and the `y` that is a variable local to the `Manipulate[]` expression. *They aren't the same thing.*

Using the replacement rule ensures that you are inserting a variable that the `Manipulate` is actually manipulating, into the expression `foo`.

Comment: You're right; this seems to work in this trivial case. This is actually the very first thing I tried, and I actually had to stop using it because of the confusion it caused when I tried to plot a list of graphs {foo1, foo2} and replace them all at once: `{foo1, foo2} /. {y -> b}`.  (It's no longer possible to colour them uniquely in this case).

Comment: @NoonSilk actually, it is: add option `Evaluated -> True` to `Plot`.

Comment: Ah! Thanks Mr. Wizard; you are right! This might be the simplest approach then (though I think the essential idea about reconsidering how I approach the general structure of my programs is a good one).

Answer (score 1):

`Manipulate` needs to see the parameters. This is mentioned in the 'Potential issues' part of its doc page. However, I think (but currently can't test this) that including a dummy statement using the parameters may work:

```
foo = Exp[2 x + y]
Manipulate[
 {x, y};Plot[foo, {x, 0, 10}], {y, 0, 10}, 
 LocalizeVariables -> False]
```

Comment: That doesn't work on my system. -1 Sorry. :-/

Comment: @mr.wizard perhaps an explicit assignment is necessary. Could you test this?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @mr.wizard something like a={x,y} or perhaps a+={x,y}.

Comment: I tried both without result, and frankly I cannot see why that would do anything.  Isn't the scoping in `Manipulate` akin to `With` rather than `Block`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm convinced some variant of this should work, but I'm deleting for now and come back to this after my vacation. This is getting a bit awkward.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, the scoping is With-like, but the dynamic tracking is Block-like. So explicit evaluation of the variables can make a difference

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It does work for me though...

Comment: @Rojo with `LocalizeVariables -> False` you are contaminating the Global namespace, which given (my understanding of) the OP's existing code is a particularly bad idea.  ([Me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zd9p4.jpg) today I guess.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I just thougth he meant he wanted that from his first comment to your answer: "I understand the risk about global assignments; arguably that's actually the feature I want - the variables are sensibly named". Is my English betraying me and he means that he actually doesn't want globals?

Comment: @Rojo I think if he is actively making definitions like `foo = Exp[2 x+y]` the Global symbols need to remain clear.  I don't think it's a matter of English comprehension, just a slightly vague programming style.

Comment: Point taken. Can't think of how to fix that without ending up with a totally different approach