# Manipulate Plot Sliders Not Working

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I'm trying to use `Manipulate` on my function so that I can adjust parameters `a`, `r`, and `b` to see how the graph changes.

When I use `Manipulate` and try to change the values of a, r, and b using the sliders, nothing happens. The graph doesn't change....what am I doing wrong?

```
f[x_] := f[x - 1] + 2 r*b (f[x - 1]) - a (f[x - 1]);
f[0] = 100000;
Manipulate[DiscretePlot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}], {r, 0, 1}, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 1, 10}]
```

I've also tried:

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[Table[f[x], {x, 0, 5}]], {r, 0, 1}, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 1, 10}]
```

but the sliders still won't do anything.

Comment: @Kuba and, perhaps more explicitly, of the following: [How are parameters evaluated for a Plot in Manipulate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10604/27951); [Manipulate using a variable defined outside of the manipulate function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31322/27951).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Steph, the problem is that `Manipulate` does not "see" the explicit dependence of `f` on the parameters you are trying to manipulate. In other words, those parameters must appear explicitly in the expression to be manipulated. You can change the definition of your function to accomplish that:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_, a_, r_, b_] := f[x - 1, a, r, b] + 2 r*b (f[x - 1, a, r, b]) - a (f[x - 1, a, r, b]);
f[0, a_, r_, b_] = 100000

Manipulate[
 DiscretePlot[f[x, a, r, b], {x, 0, 5}], {r, 0, 1}, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 1, 10}
]
```

See the following previous posts for more details:

- [How are parameters evaluated for a Plot in Manipulate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10604/27951)
- [Manipulate using a variable defined outside of the manipulate function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31322/27951)
- [Proper way to handle free variables in manipulate/plot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8625/27951)

Comment: Thank you so much. I really, really appreciate your help.
I was reading through the other answers @Kuba also pointed out but was still unable to get the syntax right for my use case.

Is there a reason, though, why only the first data point displays? Can I change the y-axis range?

Comment: @steph My code was incomplete before, sorry about that. I had neglected to change a few function calls to the new format within the definition of `f`. It should work now.

Comment: yes that does it. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I think a little discussion on how to solve the OP's problem is in order, because in this case a little preliminary work can make things much simpler.

```
f[x] == f[x - 1] + 2 r*b (f[x - 1]) - a (f[x - 1])
f[0] == 100000
```

is a very simple recursion relation which obviously has the solution

> `100000 (1 - a + 2 b r)^x`

Since we have a close form solution, why use fuss with `Table` and use `ListPlot` or any of its variants? Why not just make a simple 2D plot the closed-form expression?

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[100000 (1 - a + 2 b r)^x, {x, 0, 5}],
  {r, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {a, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {b, 1, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: demo]

#### Update

This is to address the OP comment below.

I did it my head. However, you can have Mathematica do it for you.

```
RSolve[
  {f[x] == f[x - 1] + 2 r*b (f[x - 1]) - a (f[x - 1]), f[0] == 100000}, 
  f[x], x]
```

> `{{f[x] -> 100000 (1 - a + 2 b r)^x}}`

Comment: this looks great and I would really like to know more about it, especially the basic math behind finding the closed form solution. Any chance I could ask you about that?