# Why doesn't Manipulate work if I'm not defining the parameters of my function as variables (with or without SetDelayed)?

Tags: manipulate

This is the code that failed:

```
g[x_] := x + a
Manipulate[Plot[g[x], {x, -10, 10}], {a, -10, 10}]
```

and this is the one that worked:

```
g[x_, a_] := x + a
Manipulate[Plot[g[x, a], {x, -10, 10}], {a, -10, 10}]
```

I'm planning on using codes like this to manipulate fit parameters to find good initial guesses for LinearModelFit or NoneLinearModelFit and it seems very excessive to me to have to define all of them as variables every time. Some functions have a lot of them...

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of the [`LocalizeVariables`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocalizeVariables.html) option

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manipulate Plot Sliders Not Working](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119089/manipulate-plot-sliders-not-working). In particular, `Manipulate` must be made aware of the explicit dependence of `g` on the parameters you are trying to manipulate. In other words, those parameters *must* appear explicitly in the expression to be manipulated.

Comment: I don't think LocalizeVariables will solve the problem on its own.