# How to use Solve rules as a function body?

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, replacement

`Solve` gives me an expression which I want to use as the body of a function.  Rather than run `Solve` every time inside my function body, I just want to take the rule output `Solve` already gave me, and repurpose it into something that accepts arguments.

For example, this works, but is slow because `Solve` runs in every invocation:

```
(* returns the two points where the line through pt {x1, y1} 
with slope m intersects the circle x^2 + y^2 = 100 *)
intersections[m_, x1_, y1_] :=
 Solve[y - y1 == m (x - x1) && 
    x^2 + y^2 == 100, {x, y}] /. Rule[_, val_] -> val

intersections[1, 0, 0]
(* result: *) {{-5 Sqrt[2], -5 Sqrt[2]}, {5 Sqrt[2], 5 Sqrt[2]}}
```

I've tried variations on below, but they don't work:

```
solution = Solve[y - y1 == m (x - x1) && 
     x^2 + y^2 == 100, {x, y}] /. Rule[_, val_] -> val /. {m -> #1, 
   x1 -> #2, y1 -> #3}

intersections[m_, x1_, y1_] := solution[m, x1, y1]
```

Below is almost what I want, but the rule replacements don't perform as well as real function arguments, and this is also dependent on copying around replacement symbol names:

```
solution = Solve[y - y1 == m (x - x1) && 
     x^2 + y^2 == 100, {x, y}] /. Rule[_, val_] -> val ;
intersections := solution /. { m -> #1, x1 -> #2, y1 -> #3} &;
```

How can I take the the expression `Solve` gave me, and "function-ify" it?  Copy-pasting the expressions into a function works, but obviously I don't want to do that.

Comment: Strongly related; arguably a duplicate:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6664/121

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Block` or Formal Symbols to guard against unwanted evaluation, then define your function using `Set` (`=`) rather than `SetDelayed` (`:=`).  Might as well throw in a `FullSimplify` to clean it up a bit.

```
Block[{x, y, x1, y1, m},
  intersections[m_, x1_, y1_] = FullSimplify[
    {x, y} /. Solve[y - y1 == m (x - x1) && x^2 + y^2 == 100, {x, y}]
  ]
];

intersections[1, 0, 0]
```

> ```
> {{-5 Sqrt[2], -5 Sqrt[2]}, {5 Sqrt[2], 5 Sqrt[2]}}
> ```

A look at the definition we created:

```
?intersections
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A related abstraction:

- [How to make a function like Set, but with a Block construct for the pattern names](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1992/121#1997)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to create a pure function:

```
ClearAll[functionify];
functionify[v__][sol_] := functionify[sol, Flatten@{v}];
functionify[sol_, v_] := 
  Function[v, #] &[sol /. {{r_Rule} :> Last@r, r_Rule :> Last@r}];
```

If you list the variables, `functionify[v1, v2]` uses the symbols as the arguments to the `Function` constructed from the solutions.  Example:

```
intersections = 
 Solve[y - y1 == m (x - x1) && x^2 + y^2 == 100, {x, y}] // 
  functionify[m, x1, y1]

intersections[1, 0, 0]
(*  {{-5 Sqrt[2], -5 Sqrt[2]}, {5 Sqrt[2], 5 Sqrt[2]}}  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to solve the equation once, and use the solution again, then you can try

```
sol = Solve[y - y1 == m (x - x1) && 4 x^2 + y^2 == 100, {x, y}];
intersections[mm_, xx1_, yy1_] :=
 {x /. sol /. {x1 -> xx1, m -> mm, y1 -> yy1},
  y /. sol /. {x1 -> xx1, m -> mm, y1 -> yy1}
 }
```

Now you can call it as

```
intersections[1, 2, 3]
```

which gives

```
{{(1/5)*(-1 - 4*Sqrt[31]), (1/5)*(-1 + 4*Sqrt[31])}, {4/5 - (4*Sqrt[31])/5, 4/5 + (4*Sqrt[31])/5}}
```

`Solve` is only called once as you asked for. The solution is used again and again

Comment: This is pretty much the same as my last example.