# Replace variables and redefine a function

Tags: functions, replacement

I would like to redefine a function `f(x)=1+2x^2` to a new function `g(y)=1+2y` by using the replacement `x^2 -> y`. However, in the MWE below, only 
Method 1 gives me the correct one.

What's wrong with the other two methods? Can they be repaired? I am asking because
it may not always be possible to write the replacement in terms of `x` (e.g. say, `3x^2-4x+2 -> y`).

```
    f[x_] := 1 + 2 x^2;

    g[y_] = f[y /. y -> Sqrt[y]];
    Print["Method 1: g(y)=", g[y]];

    g[y_] := Replace[f[y], y^2 -> y];
    Print["Method 2: g(y)=", g[y]];

    g[y_] = f[y /. y^2 -> y];
    Print["Method 3: g(y)=", g[y]];
```

Comment: Related: [How to use Solve rules as a function body?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15934/14303)

Answer (score 1):

For Replace you must include the levels at which to map the replacement. By default it does not map to subparts.

```
g[y_] := Replace[f[y], y^2 -> y, Infinity];
Print["Method 2: g(y)=", g[y]];
```

For /. {Replace All} your syntax is incorrect.

```
g[y_] := f[y] /. y^2 -> y;
Print["Method 3: g(y)=", g[y]];
```

Comment: Thanks. Now if I modify the replacement a bit, e.g. `1-2x^2->y` , then I expect `1+2x^2=2-(1-2x^2)=2-y`. However, 
`g[y_] := f[y] /. 1 - 2 y^2 -> y;` gives me `1+2y^2`! Am I missing something again?

Answer (score 0):

`Replace` and `ReplaceAll` functions perform only structural replacements, they don't know that some expressions may be mathematically equivalent.

To perform full change of variables you can solve equation relating one variable to another and then perform substitution using obtained solutions.

In case from  question:

```
ClearAll[xToY];
xToY = Solve[\[FormalY] == 1 - 2 \[FormalX]^2, \[FormalX]]
(* {
    {\[FormalX] -> -(Sqrt[1 - \[FormalY]]/Sqrt[2])},
    {\[FormalX] -> Sqrt[1 - \[FormalY]]/Sqrt[2]}
} *)
```

now that we have `x` in terms of `y` we can perform substitution in our function:

```
ClearAll[g];
g[\[FormalY]_] = f[\[FormalX]] /. xToY[[1]] // FullSimplify;
```

Note that I used `Set` (`=`) instead of `SetDelayed` (`:=`), so that RHS of `g` definition is evaluated and replacement and simplifications are done only once when defining `g` and not each time `g` is called. To make sure that RHS can be safely evaluated, without accidentally using some predefined value of `x` or `y`, I used formal symbols.

Now `g` is defined as:

```
??g
(* Global`g
g[\[FormalY]_]=2-\[FormalY] *)
```