# Assign Variable to NSolve

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, variable

I'm looking to create an interactive region plot in Mathematica, and it's quite a complicated region (seen below).[image]. The variable p is actually a function of y, and it's too hard to solve analytically. How do I assign p to the NSolve function? I tried the following code (below) but I don't get a number output. But when I evaluated NSolve alone without assigning it to p I got a number output. How do I do this?

[image: auCyJ.png]

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Retry your code with `NSolve` instead of `Nsolve`. Then maybe update your question. FWIW, I wouldn't name both a function and a variable by the same symbol `p`. -- See also this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/4999.
Also relevant [(3175)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3175/121), [(6669)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6669/121).
Perhaps this, too: [(15934)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15934/4999)