# How to protect function variables

Tags: function-construction, scoping

I am sure this has been asked before, but I can't seem to find the right solution.

I want a function to be the solution to a differential equation

```
refun[u_, rem_, reengy_] = 
 DSolveValue[{D[D[fun[u], u], u] + (-rem^2 + 1/4)/u^2*fun[u] - 
       u^2*fun[u] + reengy*fun[u] == 0}, fun[u], u] /. C[1] -> 0 /. 
  C[2] -> 1
```

which works out perfectly. But if I accidentally write

```
rem=1
refun[u_, rem_, reengy_] = 
 DSolveValue[{D[D[fun[u], u], u] + (-rem^2 + 1/4)/u^2*fun[u] - 
       u^2*fun[u] + reengy*fun[u] == 0}, fun[u], u] /. C[1] -> 0 /. 
  C[2] -> 1
```

the value of rem is fixed to 1 no matter what I specify as a function argument. If I were to use := to define the function I would not have this problem, but then the differential equation would be solved each time I call the function.

This seems to be a scoping issue and I tried to play around with Module and Block but couldn't get it to work. How can I protect my function from it's variables being altered by accident? Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Closely related: [(1992)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1992/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `Block` to keep external definition from being substituted while the RHS of the definition is being evaluated.

```
rem = 1;
Block[{u, rem, reengy, fun}, 
  refun[u_, rem_, reengy_] = 
   DSolveValue[{D[D[fun[u], u], u] + (-rem^2 + 1/4)/u^2*fun[u] - 
         u^2*fun[u] + reengy*fun[u] == 0}, fun[u], u] /. C[1] -> 0 /. C[2] -> 1];

Definition[refun]
(*
  refun[u_, rem_, reengy_] = (2^((1 + rem)/2) E^(u^2/2) (u^2)^((1 + rem)/2)
     LaguerreL[1/4 (-2 - reengy - 2 rem), rem, -u^2])/Sqrt[u]
*)
```

Comment: Michael, I would like to close this question as a duplicate of [(6664)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6664/121) -- do you object?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Fine with me.  Much closer than anything I found.