# How is it possible to check if a function is even or odd?

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis

I tried it like this:

```
myEvenFunction[x_] := x^2
Equal[myEvenFunction[x],myEvenFunction[-x]]
Out = x^2
Out = True

myOddFunction[x_] := x^3
Equal[myOddFunction[x], myOddFunction[-x]]
Out = x^3
Out = x^3 == -x^3
```

Shouldn't it say false here?

Comment: You are not actually defining a function. You are missing a colon `:` before the `=` sign. Function definition should be made with  `:=`

Comment: Use SameQ instead of Equal

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: oh thanks :3 i thought it meant that it should evaluate later or something.. but actullay i knew that i should put a semicolon there. Thanks.

Comment: That is exactly what it means "SetDelayed", which is defining a function, i.e., have the RHS evaluated later when x is assigned a value ..

Comment: @Bichoy Yes but in this case `x` does not have a value, so it doesn't matter if he uses `=` or `:=`.

Comment: @Algohi That won't help here, unless I misunderstand.

Comment: @Pickett .... mmm you are actually right. Sorry for that.

Comment: i am a she btw :3

Comment: but thank you all so much!! my first weeks with mathematica :q

Comment: @sudo_math Noted.

Comment: @Pickett ... but isn't it unsafe to define a function like that? What if `x` was somehow set to a value before defining the function? This shouldn't work right? (I am still learning as well ... )

Comment: @Pickett I tried it. If setting `x=1`, than `x` is immediately evaluated in the RHS as it should be .. which doesn't yield a function definition. I guess it only works when one is 100% sure there is no value for x ... yet still unsafe in my opinion.

Comment: @Bichoy Yes, it is unsafe, and it should only be used when *needed*.  You can use `Block` in some cases to make it safe; see: [(6664)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6664/121).  If you have frequent need of this kind of protected evaluation see: [(1992)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1992/121)

Comment: @Bichoy Yes, it's certainly not recommended. But sometimes if you know what you're doing, in rare cases, it can be used. For example when defining an interpolation you can do `f[x_] = 5 + Interpolation[{1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5}][x]`. In this case you don't want to execute the expensive `Interpolation` function every time you call the function. This is just a toy example, I can't come up with a real world scenario right now but I seem to remember that I've seen some.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Very useful, thanks for the hints!

Comment: @Pickett thanks for the info ... never thought about it this way :)

Comment: @Pickett `localSet` from (1992) makes such uses worry-free; I hope you'll consider using it if you do that often.

Comment: @Pickett  I tried your simple example and indeed there is a very big difference. 100,000 evaluations of the version with immediate assignment `=` requires `1.2s` whereas the version with delayed assignment `:=` requires `2.7s`... I can see how this can become an issue for more complicated functions. Thanks for the useful discussion and thanks Mr. Wizard for the hints :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than imposing `x>0` one can also do

```
FullSimplify[ ForAll[x, myOddFunction[x] == myOddFunction[-x]]]
```

which yields `False`.

Comment: Any thoughts about using `Resolve` in place of `FullSimplify` here?  (p.s. I am out of votes for the day or I would upvote.)

Comment: i like this answer the most. intuitive, simple.. Thanks :)

Comment: *intuitional. Actually i had this in mind, but couldn't transform it into a piece of code. Thanks, again. ^^ I'll try it with Resolve too.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't have any thoughts about `Resolve` because I didn't know about it until your comment!  So IDK :-P

Thanks for the accept, @sudo_math!  Welcome to Mma.SE!

Comment: Okay.  I *think* it may be faster but less robust than `FullSimplify`.  With what I do I use `ForAll` so rarely that I don't have much experience with `Resolve`.  Let me know what you find out if you remember, OK?

Comment: Sure.  I hardly every use `ForAll`, except recreationally.  So if it comes up I'll drop you a line.

Comment: @sudo_math, My limited experience with `ForAll` has been discouraging.  For instance, `FullSimplify[ForAll[x, Cos[x] == -Cos[-x]]]` does not resolve whether `Cos` is  odd or not.  Neither does `Resolve`.

Comment: Hm.  This can be fixed by wrapping everything with TrueQ, but you're right, it's not as nice a solution as I'd imagined.

Answer (score 8):

```
evenFQ[f_] := Simplify[f[t] - f[-t]] === 0
oddFQ[f_] := Simplify[f[t] + f[-t]] === 0
```

Examples:

```
ef[x_] := x^2
of[x_] := x^3

evenFQ/@ {ef, of}
```

> {True, False}

```
oddFQ/@ {ef, of}
```

> {False, True}

```
evenFQ /@ {# &, Im, Sin, Tan, Sinh, Erf}
```

> {False, False, False, False, False, False}

```
oddFQ /@ {# &, Im, Sin, Tan, Sinh, Erf}
```

> { True, True, True, True, True, True}

Comment: I'm concerned about the assumption that the arguments are real.  `evenFQ[Im]` and `oddFQ[Im]` both give true, for example, while `Im` is really odd.

Comment: @evanb, thank you; it looks like we don't need the assumption.

Comment: @kglr  Hi,  `g[x_]:=Sin[x]/(x (x^2-1)); evenFQ[g]   (*False*)`   Why?

Comment: @lotus2019, `ClearAll[g]; g[x_] := Sin[x]/(x (x^2 - 1));evenFQ[g]` gives  `True` (version 13..3.0 - Linux x86 -64bit)

Comment: @kglr Thank you, it has been successful now. It may be because I did not use `Clear` before.

Answer (score 5):

You need [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) with an assumption:

```
myOddFunction[x_] := x^3;

Simplify[
 Equal[myOddFunction[x], myOddFunction[-x]],
 x > 0
]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

[`Refine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Refine.html) also works in this case, again with the appropriate assumption:

```
Refine[Equal[myOddFunction[x], myOddFunction[-x]], x > 0]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Comment: Please be careful with regards to functions of complex variables.