# defining a function using other functions

Tags: functions

I have the following code:

```
c[theta_, xi_] = theta*xi + theta^xi^2;
xbar[theta_, xi_] = theta/xi +  xi^2 + theta^3;
f[x_, y_, theta_, xi_] = x*y*c[theta, xi]*theta*xi + xbar[theta, xi];
```

That is, I would like to define $f$ as a function $x,y,theta,xi$ using two predefined functions $c$ and $xbar$. 
But mathematica gives tag times is protected.
How to deal with it? Many thanks!

Comment: Evaluate `Remove[c, xbar, f]` before the function definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure there are no active definitions on the constituent parameters.  You can do this with [`ClearAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClearAll.html) as E.Doroskevic proposes, though I imagine you will not want to clear *all* `` Global` `` definitions.

You can [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) the Symbols in use as described in [Scoping in assigning a derivative](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6664/121).  To make this convenient I propose using the function `localSet` which I wrote for [How to make a function like Set, but with a Block construct for the pattern names](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1992/121).

```
xi = "fail!";  
y = "bad!";

localSet[c[theta_, xi_], theta*xi + theta^xi^2]
localSet[xbar[theta_, xi_], theta/xi + xi^2 + theta^3]
localSet[f[x_, y_, theta_, xi_], x*y*c[theta, xi]*theta*xi + xbar[theta, xi]]

?f
```

> Global`f
>
> f[x_, y_, theta_, xi_] = theta^3 + theta/xi + xi^2 + theta x xi (theta^xi^2 + theta xi) y

Observe that the definition is correct despite the definitions on `xi` and `y`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"] 

c[theta_, xi_] = theta*xi + theta^xi^2;
xbar[theta_, xi_] = theta/xi +  xi^2 + theta^3;
f[x_, y_, theta_, xi_] = x*y*c[theta, xi]*theta*xi + xbar[theta, xi];
```