# Variable assignment to a function

Tags: functions, replacement, assignment

I am trying to do a seemingly simple thing:

```
f[x_, y_] := x + 3 y /. {x -> -x y}
```

the output for $x=1$ and $y=2$ is 7, so it doesn't make a substitution. How can I make this work without manually substituting the variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) rather than [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html)

```
Clear[f]

f[x_, y_] := x + 3 y /. {x -> -x y}

DownValues[f]

(*  {HoldPattern[f[x_, y_]] :> (x + 3 y /. {x -> -x y})}  *)
```

[`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html) will show you the evaluation sequence

```
f[1, 2] // Trace
```

[image]

```
Clear[f]

f[x_, y_] = x + 3 y /. {x -> -x y}

(*  3 y - x y  *)

DownValues[f]

(*  {HoldPattern[f[x_, y_]] :> 3 y - x y}  *)

f[1, 2] // Trace
```

[image]

Beware that if `x` or `y` are defined before the `Set` this will fail.  For a solution see:

- [How to make a function like Set, but with a Block construct for the pattern names](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1992/121)

Comment: I added a caveat and link to your answer (as well as my vote).  I hope you do not mind.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - Thanks.