# Two seemingly equivalent formulas for bilinear interpolation yield different results

Tags: list-manipulation, interpolation

Suppose that I have a function $f:[0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and I would like to approximate it from its values in the corners of the domain by the well-known formula
$$
f(s,t) \approx (1-s,s)
\begin{pmatrix}
f(0,0) & f(0,1) \\
f(1,0) & f(1,1)
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1-t\\
t
\end{pmatrix}
\enspace,
$$
which can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation#Unit_Square).

I tried two ways of writing this in *Mathematica*:

```
bilinearExpl[f_, s_, t_] :=
        (1 - s) (1 - t) f[0, 0] + (1 - s) t f[0, 1] + (1 - t) s f[1, 0] + s t f[1, 1]
bilinearMatr[f_, s_, t_] := {1 - s, s}.{{f[0, 0], f[0, 1]}, {f[1, 0], f[1, 1]}}.{1 - t, t}
```

If I try them out, they produce results that are quite much the same:

```
bilinearExpl[f, s, t]
```

gives

[image: result of bilinearExpl]

whereas

```
bilinearMatr[f, s, t]
```

returns

[image: result of bilinearMatr]

Taking a function

```
scalarFunction[x_, y_] := x^2 y
```

as an example, they also produce the same approximation of `scalarFunction`.

```
{Plot3D[scalarFunction[s, t], {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, Mesh -> {11, 11}],
 Plot3D[bilinearExpl[scalarFunction, s, t], {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, Mesh -> {11, 11}],
 Plot3D[bilinearMatr[scalarFunction, s, t], {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, Mesh -> {11, 11}]}
```

[image: results of both methods on a scalar example]

So far so good. The same formula should work for a function $f:[0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and both methods should give the same results. *But they don't!* Take, for instance,

```
vectorFunction[x_, y_] := {x, y}
```

Then

```
{ParametricPlot[vectorFunction[s, t], {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, Mesh -> {11, 11}],
 ParametricPlot[bilinearExpl[vectorFunction, s, t], {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, Mesh -> {11, 11}],
 ParametricPlot[bilinearMatr[vectorFunction, s, t], {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, Mesh -> {11, 11}]}
```

gives

[image: results of the vector-valued example]

and the two right plots are certainly not the same.

**Question**: why are the results of the two (seemingly equivalent) formulas different?

I suppose there is some dimension mismatch of the arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, *Mathematica* knows about bilinear interpolation:

```
InterpolatingPolynomial[{{{0, 0}, f[0, 0]}, {{1, 0}, f[1, 0]},
                         {{0, 1}, f[0, 1]}, {{1, 1}, f[1, 1]}}, {s, t}]
```

For some reason, `InterpolatingPolynomial[]` chokes when `f` is vector-valued; I'm not sure why.

In any event: you seem to know about *Mathematica*'s symbolic capabilities, so you should use it to help you debug when things are not going the way you wanted them. Here's what happens when you try to bilinearly interpolate a vector-valued function with your code:

```
With[{f = {#1, #2} &}, (* bilinearExpl *)
     (1 - t) ((1 - s) f[0, 0] + s f[1, 0]) + t ((1 - s) f[0, 1] + s f[1, 1])]
   {s (1 - t) + s t, t}
```

This is the correct result; effectively, the interpolation formula's scalar form is mapped across your vector function's components.

```
With[{f = {#1, #2} &}, (* bilinearMatr *)
     {1 - s, s}.{{f[0, 0], f[0, 1]}, {f[1, 0], f[1, 1]}}.{1 - t, t}]
   {s (1 - t), s (1 - t) + t}
```

See the difference?

The cure in this case is to reorder your dot products:

```
With[{f = {#1, #2} &},
     {1 - t, t}.({1 - s, s}.{{f[0, 0], f[0, 1]}, {f[1, 0], f[1, 1]}})]
   {s (1 - t) + s t, t}
```

(Note the use of parentheses so that the matrix-vector product is done first.)

The reordered dot product formula still makes sense even if the vector-valued function has more than two components:

```
With[{f = {#1 - #2, #1 + #2, #1 #2} &},
     {1 - t, t}.({1 - s, s}.{{f[0, 0], f[0, 1]}, {f[1, 0], f[1, 1]}})]
   {s (1 - t) + (-1 + s) t, s (1 - t) + (1 + s) t, s t}
```

while your version will choke:

```
With[{f = {#1 - #2, #1 + #2, #1 #2} &},
     {1 - s, s}.{{f[0, 0], f[0, 1]}, {f[1, 0], f[1, 1]}}.{1 - t, t}]

Dot::dotsh: Tensors {{s, s, 0}, {-1 + s, 1 + s, s}} and {1 - t, t} have
incompatible shapes.
   {{s, s, 0}, {-1 + s, 1 + s, s}}.{1 - t, t}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this might help.  [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html) documentation says:

[image]

Now consider this, noting the operational grouping via parentheses:

```
rules = {a -> {a1, a2}, b -> {b1, b2}, c -> {c1, c2}, d -> {d1, d2}};

{r, s}.({{a, b}, {c, d}} /. rules).{t, u}

({r, s}.{{a, b}, {c, d}}.{t, u}) /. rules
```

> ```
> {(a1 r + c1 s) t + (a2 r + c2 s) u, (b1 r + d1 s) t + (b2 r + d2 s) u}
>
> {(a1 r + c1 s) t + (b1 r + d1 s) u, (a2 r + c2 s) t + (b2 r + d2 s) u}
> ```

One possible approach:

```
ClearAll[bilinearMatr]

Block[{f, s, t},
  bilinearMatr[f_, s_, t_] =
    {1 - s, s}.{{f[0, 0], f[0, 1]}, {f[1, 0], f[1, 1]}}.{1 - t, t}
];

{ParametricPlot[vectorFunction[s, t], {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, Mesh -> {11, 11}], 
 ParametricPlot[bilinearExpl[vectorFunction, s, t], {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  Mesh -> {11, 11}], 
 ParametricPlot[bilinearMatr[vectorFunction, s, t], {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  Mesh -> {11, 11}]}
```

[image]

For automation of this [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html)/[`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) work-around see:

- [How to make a function like Set, but with a Block construct for the pattern names](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1992/121)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the trick with the Block seems quite useful. However, I can accept only one answer.