# How to create Functions that have Compiled functions effectively

Tags: programming, function-construction, packages, compile, scoping

I'm about to build a package that will provide lots of simple functions.  I want these functions to run as fast as possible when evaluating numerically but still provide symbolic results when needed. To cut down on coding errors I only want to define the core function once. I have a first cut at something that seems to work but when I look at the definition with `FullDefinition[]` I see things that I do not expect.

Here is a definition of one of the functions:

```
    Module[{code, a, v, i, W},
  code = {
    a (Cos[v] Cos[W] - Cos[i] Sin[v] Sin[W]),
    a (Cos[i] Cos[W] Sin[v] + Cos[v] Sin[W]),
    a Sin[i] Sin[v]};
  SATFast = With[
    {
     Ccode = code
     },
    Compile[{{a, _Real}, {i, _Real}, {W, _Real}, {v, _Real}},
     Ccode
     ,
     CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}, 
     CompilationTarget -> "C"
     ]
    ];

  With[{
    fun = SATFast
    },
   (*Define the special case first!*)

   SAT[av_?NumericQ, iv_?NumericQ, Wv_?NumericQ, vv_?NumericQ] := 
    fun[av, iv, Wv, vv];
   SAT[av_, iv_, Wv_, vv_] := 
    Evaluate[code /. {a -> av, i -> iv, W -> Wv, v -> vv}];
   ]
  ];
```

This will ultimately be in a package where I will have a `usage` statement for the function `SAT` but not for the function `SATFast`. I expect to be able to use `SATFast` inside of other functions within the package.

I'm concerned with the output of `FullDefinition[SAT]`.

The first line of output, which was displayed as a `CompiledFunction[]` object in Mathematica but shows more detail here is as follows:

```
SAT[av$_?NumericQ, iv$_?NumericQ, Wv$_?NumericQ, vv$_?NumericQ] := 
 CompiledFunction[{10, 11.1, 5468}, {
Blank[Real], 
Blank[Real], 
Blank[Real], 
Blank[Real]}, {{3, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 1}, {3, 0, 2}, {3, 0, 3}, {3, 1, 
   0}}, {}, {0, 0, 13, 0, 
   1}, {{40, 2, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 4}, {40, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 0, 5}, {40, 1, 
    3, 0, 3, 3, 0, 6}, {40, 2, 3, 0, 3, 3, 0, 7}, {40, 1, 3, 0, 2, 3, 
    0, 8}, {16, 7, 5, 9}, {16, 4, 6, 8, 10}, {19, 10, 11}, {13, 9, 11,
     9}, {16, 0, 9, 11}, {16, 4, 5, 6, 9}, {16, 7, 8, 10}, {13, 9, 10,
     9}, {16, 0, 9, 10}, {40, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 9}, {16, 0, 9, 6, 
    12}, {34, 1, 3, 11, 10, 12, 3, 0}, {1}}, 
Function[{a$5296, i$5296, W$5296, v$5296}, 
Block[{Compile`$9, Compile`$7, Compile`$10, Compile`$3, Compile`$11}, 
     Compile`$9 = Cos[i$5296]; Compile`$7 = Cos[
       W$5296]; Compile`$10 = Sin[v$5296]; Compile`$3 = Cos[
       v$5296]; Compile`$11 = Sin[W$5296]; {
      a$5296 (Compile`$3 Compile`$7 - Compile`$9 Compile`$10 Compile`$\
11), a$5296 (
        Compile`$9 Compile`$7 Compile`$10 + Compile`$3 Compile`$11), 
       a$5296 Sin[i$5296] Compile`$10}]], Evaluate, 
LibraryFunction[
   "/home/paulb/.Mathematica/ApplicationData/CCompilerDriver/\
BuildFolder/trail-19983/compiledFunction1.so", 
    "compiledFunction1", {{Real, 0, "Constant"}, {
     Real, 0, "Constant"}, {Real, 0, "Constant"}, {
     Real, 0, "Constant"}}, {Real, 1}]][av$, iv$, Wv$, vv$]
```

Line two:

```
SAT[av$_, iv$_, Wv$_, 
  vv$_] := {av$ (Cos[vv$] Cos[Wv$] - Cos[iv$] Sin[vv$] Sin[Wv$]), 
  av$ (Cos[iv$] Cos[Wv$] Sin[vv$] + Cos[vv$] Sin[Wv$]), 
  av$ Sin[iv$] Sin[vv$]}
```

So far these two lines are what I would expect but then I also get the following:

```
Attributes[av$] = {Temporary}

Attributes[iv$] = {Temporary}

Attributes[Wv$] = {Temporary}

Attributes[vv$] = {Temporary}

Attributes[a$5296] = {Temporary}

Attributes[i$5296] = {Temporary}

Attributes[W$5296] = {Temporary}

Attributes[v$5296] = {Temporary}

Attributes[Compile`$9] = {Temporary}

Attributes[Compile`$7] = {Temporary}

Attributes[Compile`$10] = {Temporary}

Attributes[Compile`$3] = {Temporary}

Attributes[Compile`$11] = {Temporary}
```

Am I not scoping my variables correctly?  Is there a better way to scope the dummy variables in the symbolic definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that what you are doing is fine and that the [`Temporary`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Temporary.html) attributes may be ignored.  Symbols created by `Module` bear this by default but it should not affect the definitions you create.

Using [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) in place of [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) will clean up the definitions somewhat, but understand what it does before applying it blindly.

```
Block[{code, a, v, i, W}, 
  code = {a (Cos[v] Cos[W] - Cos[i] Sin[v] Sin[W]), 
    a (Cos[i] Cos[W] Sin[v] + Cos[v] Sin[W]), a Sin[i] Sin[v]};

  SATFast = 
   Compile[{{a, _Real}, {i, _Real}, {W, _Real}, {v, _Real}}, #, 
      CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}] &[code];

  (SAT[a_?NumericQ, i_?NumericQ, W_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] := #[a, i, W, v]) &[
   SATFast];

  SAT[a_, i_, W_, v_] = code;
];


FullDefinition[SAT]
```

> ```
> SAT[a_?NumericQ, i_?NumericQ, W_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] := 
>  CompiledFunction[Argument count : 4 Argument types : {_Real, _Real, _Real, _Real}][
>   a, i, W, v]
>
> SAT[a_, i_, W_, v_] = {a (Cos[v] Cos[W] - Cos[i] Sin[v] Sin[W]), 
>   a (Cos[i] Cos[W] Sin[v] + Cos[v] Sin[W]), a Sin[i] Sin[v]}     
>
> Attributes[Compile`$4] = {Temporary}
>
> Attributes[Compile`$2] = {Temporary}
>
> Attributes[Compile`$5] = {Temporary}
>
> Attributes[Compile`$1] = {Temporary}
>
> Attributes[Compile`$6] = {Temporary}
> ```

Possibly of interest:

- [How to make a function like Set, but with a Block construct for the pattern names](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1992/121)
- [Expressions containing globally undefined symbols inside a function where they are defined](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69590/121)

Comment: J. M. thanks for the correction!

Comment: Anytime. ;) ${}$

Comment: I like the application of the pure function. Am I to understand that that is taking the place of the way I used the `With[]` command? Why do you use the `Set` with the `code` Why not do `(SAT[a_,...]:=#)&[code]`

Comment: @c186282 Yes, I used it in place of `With`; because `Function` is not a scoping construct in the general manner that `With` is it does not rename Symbols inside it (ref: [(20776)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20776/121)), making the final definitions a little cleaner (IMHO).  When the *entire* RHS can/should be evaluated it is cleaner to use `Set` as that is just what it does.  The `Function` method (or `With`) is needed for piecewise evaluation of the RHS.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one possibility. Write out the body as a separate block wrapped in `Hold[]`, and then use either of `Compile[]` or `Function[]` as needed. This approach has been used in some of the add-on packages that accompany *Mathematica*:

```
(* for more complicated cases, you'd have something like Hold[Module[(* stuff *)]] *)
SATBody := Hold[{a (Cos[v] Cos[W] - Cos[i] Sin[v] Sin[W]),
                 a (Cos[i] Cos[W] Sin[v] + Cos[v] Sin[W]), a Sin[i] Sin[v]}]

SATCompiled = Function[body, 
                       Compile[{{a, _Real}, {i, _Real}, {W, _Real}, {v, _Real}}, body, 
                               CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True},
                               CompilationTarget -> "C"], {HoldAll}] @@ SATBody;

SATUncompiled = Function[body, Function @@ Hold[{a, i, W, v}, body], {HoldAll}] @@ SATBody;

SAT[a_, i_, W_, v_] := If[Apply[And, NumericQ /@ {a, i, W, v}], (* or some other test *)
                          SATCompiled[a, i, W, v], 
                          SATUncompiled[a, i, W, v]]
```

Comment: "injector pattern" would make this more comfortable, IMHO

Comment: Yes, `With[{body = SATBody}, SATCompiled = Compile[(* stuff *)]]`, would work too, I guess.